# Android: fail to write a system service to copy file from /mnt/sdcard to /system/media

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

I just write an Android system service and it works.

```
/*
 *   framework/base/services/java/com/android/server/MyService.java
 */

package com.android.server;

import android.util.Log;
import android.os.IMyManager;

    class MyService extends IMyManager.Stub
    {

            final String TAG = "MyService";

            public MyService()
            {
                    Log.i(TAG,"MyService is constructed!"); 
            }
    }
```

It will print "MyService is constructed" when booting before going to launcher application.

But it failed when I wanted to copy a file from /mnt/sdcard to /system/media

```
/*
 *   framework/base/services/java/com/android/server/MyService.java
 */

package com.android.server;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.util.Log;
import android.os.IMyManager;

class MyService extends IMyManager.Stub
{
        final String TAG = "MyService";

        public MyService()
        {
                Log.i(TAG,"MyService is constructed!");

                try {
                    InputStream input = new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/bootanimation.zip");
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/system/media/bootanimation.zip");

                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                    long total = 0;
                    int count;
                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }

                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Exception in MyService");
                }

                Log.i(TAG,"MyService finishes!");
        }
}
```

The error message is FileNotFoundException.
But I'm certain that there's a bootanimation.zip under /mnt/sdcard

```
946:02-11 06:44:54.796   608   608 W System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/bootanimation.zip: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
947:02-11 06:44:54.796   608   608 W System.err:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
948:02-11 06:44:54.796   608   608 W System.err:    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
949:02-11 06:44:54.796   608   608 W System.err:    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
950:02-11 06:44:54.796   608   608 W System.err:    at com.android.server.MyService.<init>(MyService.java:27)
951:02-11 06:44:54.796   608   608 W System.err:    at com.android.server.ServerThread.initAndLoop(SystemServer.java:195)
952:02-11 06:44:54.796   608   608 W System.err:    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1182)
953:02-11 06:44:54.796   608   608 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
954:02-11 06:44:54.796   608   608 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:770)
955:02-11 06:44:54.796   608   608 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
956:02-11 06:44:54.796   608   608 W System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
957:02-11 06:44:54.796   608   608 W System.err:    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
958:02-11 06:44:54.796   608   608 W System.err:    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:166)
959:02-11 06:44:54.796   608   608 W System.err:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:392)
960:02-11 06:44:54.796   608   608 W System.err:    ... 8 more
```

Anyone knows the root cause?
Is it because when booting, the /mnt/sdcard/ has not mounted already?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you gave the permissions in manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Hi, I was writing a system service, not an application. It seems that there's no AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: So, What you are doing is not an android application??

Comment: You can try giving path as Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()

Answer (score 0):

Your `Exception` is created due to these following tow line...

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/bootanimation.zip");
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/system/media/bootanimation.zip");
```

The constructors, `FileInputStream()` and `FileOutputStream`, expects a `File` object to pass in as their arguments. But you are passing them `String` value.

So to solve this problem, at First, you should create `File` object using those path by passing them into `File()` constructor. At second, pass those created `File` object into `InputStream` and `OutputStream` to read those files. I'm giving you the corrected that should be as follows....

```
//you should not write /mnt/sdcard/ as hardcoded...instead use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()

File inputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "bootanimation.zip");
File outputFile = new File("/system/media/bootanimation.zip");

InputStream input = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

I think, after this you will get everything alright.